# Python: Deadlock of a single lock in multiprocessing

Tags: python, thread-safety, multiprocessing, mutex, python-3.4

I'm using pyserial to acquire data with multiprocessing. The way I share data is very simple. So:

I have member objects in my class:

```
self.mpManager = mp.Manager()
self.shared_return_list = self.mpManager.list()
self.shared_result_lock = mp.Lock()
```

I call my multiprocessing process this way:

```
process = mp.Process(target=do_my_stuff, 
args=(self.shared_stopped, self.shared_return_list, self.shared_result_lock)
)
```

where `do_my_stuff` is a global function.

Now The part the fills the list in the process function:

```
if len(acqBuffer) > acquisitionSpecs["LengthToPass"]:
    shared_lock.acquire()
    shared_return_list.extend(acqBuffer)
    del acqBuffer[:]
    shared_lock.release()
```

And the part that takes that to the local thread for use is:

```
while len(self.acqBuffer) <= 0 and (not self.stopped):
    #copy list from shared buffer and empty it
    self.shared_result_lock.acquire()
    self.acqBuffer.extend(self.shared_return_list)
    del self.shared_return_list[:]
    self.shared_result_lock.release()
```

**The problem**:

Although there's only 1 lock, my program is occasionally ending in a deadlock somehow! After waiting some time, my program freezes. After adding prints before and after the locks, I found that it freezes at a lock and reaches a deadlock somehow.

If I use a recursive lock, `RLock()`, it works with no problems. Not sure whether I should do that.

How is this possible? Am I doing something wrong? I expect if both processes try to acquire the lock, they should block until the other process unlocks the lock.

Comment: You have a `shared_lock.acquire()` and a `self.shared_result_lock.acquire()`.  It's not really clear what the `shared_lock` variable is?

Comment: @Gerrat It's the same lock passed as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out it's not a deadlock. My fault! The problem was that the data acquired from the device is sometimes so huge that copying the data through

```
shared_return_list.extend(acqBuffer)
del acqBuffer[:]
```

Takes a very long time that the program freezes. I solved this issue by moving data in chunks and by limiting the amount of data to be pulled from the device.

Answer (score 1):

Without having a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), it's difficult to know if there's something else going on in your code or not.

One possibility is that there is an exception thrown after a lock is acquired.  Try wrapping each of your locked sections in a try/finally clause.  Eg.

```
try:
    shared_lock.acquire()
    shared_return_list.extend(acqBuffer)
    del acqBuffer[:]
finally:
    shared_lock.release()
```

and:

```
try:
    self.shared_result_lock.acquire()
    self.acqBuffer.extend(self.shared_return_list)
    del self.shared_return_list[:]
finally:
    self.shared_result_lock.release()
```

You could even add exception clauses, and log any exceptions raised, if this turns out to be the issue.

Comment: +1 for teaching me something I didn't know, which is how to implement a "lock_guard" with `finally`. Thanks! It didn't resolve the issue, though.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist: Too bad.  I really thought that would have been the issue.  If you were able to create a small example other people could run, that would likely either lead you to discover the issue, or help someone else help you better.

Comment: Actually my SSCCE doesn't have the problem. So I'm still investigating what's causing it. Thanks :)